# Autofill data from previous cell to next cell in openpyxl

Tags: python, automation, openpyxl

I am totally new in python. Just recently Getting to learn python coding.
My purpose is to automate some daily tasks of excel. For that reason, i am using pycharm and for as excel library i am using openpyxl.

Using couple of days coding, i have just now learned to write and read data in cell, manipulating with rows & columns. Thats all

But now i have got stuck in formula part. I have excel file with large data along with a very complex and big formula (5000 Lenght Characters) in a certain column.

Now i want to dragged the formula down into a couple range of cells in that column. i want to automate that by python code. For example in vba there is a "autofill" api macro code to automate cell data. Same as Xlwings there is also autofill option, instead of putting whole big formula in python.

So is there any code in python/openpyxl similar like this? please provide suggestion whether i am gonna use openpyxl or switch to other liberies (Xlwing, xlswrite)?

Comment: The dragging of formulas is an Excel function. Openpyxl edits the underlying xlms that make up an XLSX file. It is not, and does not have any interaction with Excel. However Openpyxl does include an API to [translate](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formula.html?highlight=translation#translating-formulae-from-one-location-to-another) formulas from one cell to another cell or cells.

Comment: When attempting to submit the question, you were likely shown a message asking you to provide more details, so please do so. Including nonsense filler text to get around system quality restrictions is bordering on abusing the system and can eventually lead to [question bans](/help/question-bans) and/or [suspensions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).